# MySQL JOIN table with return NULL or 0

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to create JOIN some tables. The idea is to display the selected 0 0r 1.name for the same name.if not value should be NULL or 0 else 1.

Sample Data

TABLE 1

```
ID   NAME
------------
1    Zebra

2    Monkey

3    Lion

4    Rabbit
```

TABLE 2

```
ID  ID_table1  Name_table1
--------------------------
1       1        ZEBRA   
2       3        Lion   
3       3        Lion
4       1        Zebra
5       2        Monkey
6       3        Lion  
7       4        Rabbit
```

if i join table and select value from TABLE 2 where Id is 2

RESULT

```
ID    NAME   Selected
--------------------- 
1    Zebra      0
2    Monkey     0
3    Lion       1  
4    Rabbit     0
```

Comment: Does your table_2 have all the three columns?

Answer (score 1):

Need to use `LEFT JOIN` and `CASE`

```
SELECT T1.ID, NAME , case when T2.ID_Table1 is null then 0 else 1 end as value
FROM
Table1 T1
LEFT JOIN( select ID_table1 
  FROM Table2
  where ID =2
 ) T2
on T1.ID = T2.ID_table1
```

Comment: Maybe I am missing something here, why do we need to join the tables when everything that is there in table_1 is present in table_2?

Comment: @RashmiPandit, as out put is completely based on T1, in the example table 2 had all values from T1 but it might not be needed always. looks like a assignment to test usage of LEFT JOIN

Comment: +1 Also noticed that the execution plan for your query shows it to be more performant

Comment: why do you even have a case? why not use the built in functions?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to join the two tables.

You can do this using only the Table_2

```
DECLARE @selected INT
SET @selected = 2
SELECT DISTINCT
        id_table1 AS ID ,
        name_table1 AS Name ,
        SUM(CASE WHEN ID = @selected THEN 1
                 ELSE 0
            END) AS selected
FROM    Table_2
GROUP BY ID_Table1 ,
        name_table1
ORDER BY id_table1
```

Result:

```
ID  Name    selected
1   ZEBRA   0
2   Monkey  0
3   Lion    1
4   Rabbit  0
```

Answer (score 0):

to what i was referring in my comment you should just use a COUNT()

```
SELECT t.ID, t.NAME, COUNT(t1.id_table1)
FROM Table1 t
LEFT JOIN
(   SELECT ID_table1 
    FROM Table2
    WHERE ID=2
)t1 ON t.ID = t1.ID_table1
GROUP BY t.id
```

[**DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1d842/1)